# Flutter MaterialApp home based on futureBuilder

Tags: flutter, future

When my app starts up, it detects whether the user is logged in or not (with firebase) and based on this check, it shows the homepage or the login page. Up to now everything is fine, but I would like to add one more layer.

The user can login as normal user or as admin.
So the check should be not only on the authentication state, but also on the "level" of the user, and show different pages, based on the user level.

I get the user level with a query on the firestore database, so it's a Future.
This is the code i'm using:

```
  final usersCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  User loggedUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  Future<InfoUtente> userInfo;
  String livelloLogin;

  // here I get the user from the firestore database, based on the authenticated user id
  Future<InfoUtente> fetchInfoUtente() async {
    final response = await usersCollection
        .where(
          'uid',
          isEqualTo: loggedUser.uid,
        )
        .get();
    return InfoUtente.fromFireStore(response.docs.first);
  }
  
  // here I return the page based on the user authentication "level"
  Future<Widget> widgetChoice() async {
    if (!isLogged)
      return LoginNewPage();
    else {
      userInfo.then(
        (value) {
          livelloLogin = value.loginLevel;
          if (livelloLogin == 'struttura')
            return StrutturaPage();
          else
            return MainPage();
        },
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      
      // the homepage of the material app is a future builder
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: widgetChoice(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Widget> widget) {
          if (!widget.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return widget.data;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

something is not right because it always shows the circular progress indicator.
What am I doing wrong?
Is this the correct way of doing this or am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no data fetched or found, your screen will stuck on loading infinitely. Update your builder's implementation as

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Widget> widget) {
        if(widget.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
          if (!widget.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('No Data exists')
            );
          }
          return widget.data;
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
```

And update your `widgetChoice` as

```
Future<Widget> widgetChoice() async {
    if (!isLogged)
      return LoginNewPage();
    else {
      var userInfo = await fetchInfoUtente();
      livelloLogin = userInfo.loginLevel;
      if (livelloLogin == 'struttura')
        return StrutturaPage();
      else
        return MainPage();
    }
  }
```

Comment: this one works better, but it keeps showing no data exists even if the function WidgetChoice returns the correct widget.. what am I missing here?

Comment: because your future complete its working before it executes the live login checks. made an edit check

Comment: wooow! that was the problem!! thank you I appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

If i'm right you have to call the future function like that:

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: widgetChoice,
```

Without `()`

Comment: uhm... actually no, it doesn't work without the brackets